# pyLDAvis not showing not showing Top-30 Most Relevant terms for a topic

Tags: python

I am working on Topic Modelling using `pyLDAvis` and `gensim`.

So I created the dictionary and the corpus from my dataframe

```
from gensim import corpora

df_corpus["translated"] = df_corpus["translated"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" "))
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(df_corpus["translated"]) 
texts = list(df_corpus["translated"])
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts] 
print(id2word)
print(corpus[:1][0][:30])
```

This outputs:

```
# Dictionary
Dictionary(9169 unique tokens: ['a', 'abrupt', 'after', 'against', 'ago']...)
# Corpus
[(0, 14), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 6), (10, 2), (11, 7), (12, 14), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (16, 1), (17, 5), (18, 1), (19, 2), (20, 1), (21, 1), (22, 1), (23, 1), (24, 7), (25, 3), (26, 3), (27, 1), (28, 3), (29, 1)]
```

Sample of `df['translated']`:

```
{'ChrisCowlin': 'tottenham news transfer window update dele alli latest di maria link signing max aarons jose wants brand new with from on al match officials for the tottenham v brentford semifinal referee michael deanassistant referees transfer talk with from the january transfer window potential signings for spurs had good fun filming this episode with all the latest transfer talk surrounding make sure to g tottenham news transfer window update elite football to carry on'}
```

Then I trained the model here are the results:

```
Average topic coherence: -0.2570.
Perplexity:  -7.04576621370004
```

Then I tried to visualise the topics using pyLDAvis like so:

```
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(model,corpus,id2word,mds='mmds')
```

### But this is the output without the Top-30 Most Relevant Terms for a Topic being labelled:

[image]

### When it should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: `df_corpus["translated"]`??

Comment: @Ajay I just included a sample in the question

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.  In case it helps:

I have a Jupyter notebook that works fine on one computer, and gets the same results on a second computer but has the pyLDAvis top 30 labels missing on that second computer.  I noticed they have very different versions installed.  The labels are present in pyLDAvis 2.1.2, and missing in version 3.2.0.  Many other modules are different versions between the two systems though. E.g. ipykernel 5.4.3 vs 5.3.4 (i.e. newer in the system with the older pyLDAvis).  Both of these systems are a bit of a version nightmare as they are Anaconda on Windows 10 with a number of packages installed via pip.  I've been meaning to do a clean re-install, but in the meantime would be happy to see if my two systems could help troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Thanks I will  check what version I am using and then downgrade to see if it works.